# What is the difference between a C# windows application (connecting to an SQL Server) compiled in Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

A compiled EXE application programmed in C# using visual studio 2010 can connect to an SQL Server but an error occurs during pre-login handshake (certificate chain was issued by untrusted authority), however the same EXE compiled using Visual Studio 2005 does not prompt this error.

Comment: What versions of .Net is the project set to compile under in the different visual studios?  You will probably find that they are different and the later version is more security conscious.

Comment: They are both compiled targeting .NET framework 2 though the test environment already has .NET framework 4.5 installed